# Permitting nested parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I want to permit a long params hash, I tried to follow [strong params docs on nested params](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters), but I got a few errors, I can't find what is wrong.

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name,
                                  :scale,
                                  :unit,
                                  :colorFormat,
                                  :artboards => [
                                    {
                                      :layers => [
                                        {
                                          :objectID, :type, :name,
                                          :rect => {
                                            :x, :y, :width, :height
                                          },
                                          :rotation, :radius, :borders => [], :fills => [], :shadows => [], :opacity, :styleName
                                        }
                                      ],
                                      :notes => [
                                        {
                                          :rect => {
                                            :x, :y, :width, :height
                                          },
                                          :note
                                        }
                                      ], :pageName, :pageObjectID, :name, :slug, :objectID, :width, :height, :imagePath
                                    }
                                  ],
                                  :slices => [
                                    :name, :objectID,
                                    :rect => {
                                      :x, :y, :width, :height
                                    },
                                    :exportable => [
                                      {
                                        :name, :density, :format, :path
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  ],
                                  :colors => [
                                  ]
                                 )
end
```

Here are the errors I got:

```
projects_controller.rb:60: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...=> [ {:layers => [ { :objectID, :type, :name, :rect => {:x, ...
...                               ^
projects_controller.rb:60: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...ID, :type, :name, :rect => {:x, :y, :width, :height}, :rotat...
...                               ^
projects_controller.rb:60: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
... } ], :notes => [{:rect => {:x, :y, :width, :height}, :note}...
...                               ^
projects_controller.rb:60: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...:name, :objectID, :rect => {:x, :y, :width, :height}, :expor...
...                               ^
projects_controller.rb:60: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...eight}, :exportable => [{:name, :density, :format, :path}], ...
...                               ^):
```

I don't know why it's expecting `=>` instead of `,` while I just need a scalar value not an array or hash. What I am missing here?

**EDIT**

Now I fixed most of the params:

```
  params.require(:project).permit(:slug,
                                  :scale,
                                  :unit,
                                  :color_format,
                                  artboards: [
                                    :page_name, :page_object_id, :name, :slug, :object_id, :width, :height, :image_path,
                                    layers: [
                                      :object_id, :type, :name, :rotation, :radius, :opacity, :style_name, :font_size, :font_face, :text_align, :letter_spacing, :line_height, :content, rect: [], css: [], borders: [], fills: [], shadows: [], color: []
                                    ],
                                    notes: [
                                      :note,
                                      rect: [
                                        :x, :y, :width, :height
                                      ]
                                    ]
                                  ],
                                  slices: [
                                    :name, :object_id,
                                    rect: [
                                      :x, :y, :width, :height
                                    ],
                                    exportable: []
                                  ],
                                  colors: []
                                 )
```

I got:

```
Unpermitted parameter: rect
Unpermitted parameter: rect
Unpermitted parameters: rect, fills
Unpermitted parameters: rect, color
Unpermitted parameters: rect, borders
Unpermitted parameters: rect, color
Unpermitted parameters: exportable, rect
```

Here is a sample of a JSON: https://jsonblob.com/57cb9e08e4b0dc55a4f2b785

Answer (score 3):

it seems to be saying because you wrapped those symbols in `{}`, it is expecting a hash, which means you need to have a key and value, like `:objectID => some_value`

In this line,

```
{ :objectID, :type, :name, :rect => {:x, ...
```

it is expecting something like

```
{ :objectID => val1, :type => val2, :name => val3, :rect => {:x, ...
```

This is taken straight from strong parameter docs on nested parameters,

```
params.permit(:name, {:emails => []}, :friends => [ :name, { :family => [ :name ], :hobbies => [] }])
```

notice that everything inside `{}` always have an key-value pair. such as `{:emails => []}`, and `{ :family => [ :name ], :hobbies => [] }`

Comment: Thanks @davidhu2000, that worked, but I got this error when accessing the nested hashes: http://imgur.com/a/75et8